# Configure Maven project as Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

How can I configure a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline as Maven project?

For a Maven project in Jenkins I get the option.:

> Build Triggers

> Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built

[image: Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built]

But for a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline I don't get that option.

How to get that option for a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline with a `Jenkinsfile`. In the file I configured the following:

```
triggers {
  upstream(upstreamProjects: "PROJECT_NAME_IN_JENKINS", threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

So the build is triggered everytime the dependant upstream project is build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

dEE.

I think it is not possible. But I can share workaround with you.

Create maven project job, configure webhooks between jenkins and gitlab. In Source Code Management add as much branches as you want.

[image: add several branches]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins by choosing "Multibranch pipeline " in the option

[image]

There is no `poll SCM` but you can use `Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers` instead. Also take advantage of WebHook if the SCM you use gives that option

[image]

and about `Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built` this option -  I dont think there is a way to do this with multibranch pipeline because this option comes with [maven-plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin/) and can only available in `Maven Project`. But with out this you can achive the same scenario in different way by following good practice.

- Build the dependent project seperately and keep the generate artifact in Nexus or Artifactory, so that the other job will pull independently.
- Always make a good practice to use RELEASE version not SNAPSHOT version